# Chartjs para Kendo-ui

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-ui, telerik, chartjs

Estou mudando do [Chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/) para o [Kendo-ui](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui). (Minha empresa tem a licença)

Estou tendo alguns problemas em personalizar o [Radar Chart](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/radar-charts/index) que estou tentando usar.

1) Remover linhas que dividem o gráfico. A cruz que seria o `angleShowLineOut = false` no **Chartjs**.
2) O que no **Chartjs** é `scaleLineColor` não consigo encontrar algo equivalente no **Kendo-ui** para personalizar a cor da *linha da escala*.
3) Não consigo personalizar as cores das **linhas dos dados** como no **Chartjs** na propriedade `strokeColor`.
Mesmo olhando [essa documentação](http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart) gigante tenho tido dificuldades...

Vejam esse [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jedarc/y4trpr15/12/).
Segue código abaixo também:

```js
// Chartjs
var radarChartData = {
  labels: ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"],
    
    datasets: [
   {
    label: "Linha1",
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
    strokeColor: "red",
    pointColor: "red",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    data: [2,2,2,2]
   },
   {
    label: "Linha2",
    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0)",
    strokeColor: "green",
    pointColor: "green",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    data: [8,8,8,8]
   }
  ]
 };

 window.myRadar = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Radar(radarChartData, {
            responsive: true,
        //scaleShowLabels : true,
        animationSteps: 80,
        animationEasing: "easeOutQuart",
        scaleOverride: true,
        scaleSteps: 10,
        scaleStepWidth: 1,
        scaleStartValue: 0,
        angleShowLineOut : false,
        scaleLineColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
        
        legendTemplate : '<% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++) { %>'
                    +'<h3 style=\"color:<%=datasets[i].strokeColor%>\">.'
                    +'<% if (datasets[i].label) { %><%= datasets[i].label %><% }%>'
                +'<% } %></h3>',
        
        //Number - Pixel width of the angle line
    angleLineWidth : 100,

    //String - Point label font declaration
    pointLabelFontFamily : "Arial",

    //String - Point label font weight
    pointLabelFontStyle : "normal",

    //Number - Point label font size in pixels
    pointLabelFontSize : 20,

    //String - Point label font colour
    pointLabelFontColor : "black",
         // String - Template string for single tooltips
            tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label %>: <%}%><%= value %>",
            // String - Template string for multiple tooltips
            multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= datasetLabel %> : <%= value %>",
        });

document.getElementById("legendDiv").innerHTML = window.myRadar.generateLegend();


//********************************************************************

// Kendo-ui

function createChart() {
            $("#chart").kendoChart({
              renderAs: "canvas",
              legend: {
                position: "bottom"
              },
              seriesDefaults: {
                type: "radarLine"
              },
                
              series: [{
                  colorField: "valueColor",
                  data: [
                      {
                          name: "Linha 1",
                    data: [2, 2, 2, 2],
                          valueColor: "red"
                      },{
                          name: "Linha 2",
                          data: [4, 4, 4, 4],
                          valueColor: "green"
                      }]
    }],
                
              categoryAxis: {
                categories: ["Item1",
                             "Item2",
                             "Item3",
                             "Item4"]
              },
              valueAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 10,
                majorUnit: 1,
                visible: false
              },
              tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                format: "${0}"
              }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(createChart);
        $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
```

```css
#canvas-container {
        width: 100%;
        border: 2px solid #8AC007;
        background-color: white;
    }

    canvas {
        display: inline;
        background-color: white;
    }

    #legendDiv {
        text-align: left;
    }
#chart{
    width: 100%;
      height: 400px;
      border: 2px solid #8AC007;
      background-color: white;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.805/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.805/styles/kendo.material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.805/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.chartjs.org/assets/Chart.js"></script>
<div class="demo-section k-content" id="chart-container">
        <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>
<br/>
<div id="canvas-container">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <div id="legendDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, tentativa e erro.
Duvida nº 1: Ainda não consegui.
**Dúvida nº 2**: 
Basta usar [`valueAxis.majorGridLines.color`](http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-valueAxis.majorGridLines.color). O código ficaria assim:

```
           valueAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 10,
                majorUnit: 1,
                visible: false,
                majorGridLines: {
                            color: "black"
                            }
              },
```

**Dúvida nº 3**:
Ao invés de usar:

```
              series: [{
                  colorField: "valueColor",
                  data: [
                      {
                          name: "Linha 1",
                          data: [2, 2, 2, 2],
                          valueColor: "red"
                      },{
                          name: "Linha 2",
                          data: [4, 4, 4, 4],
                          valueColor: "green"
                      }]
                }],
```

Basta usar:

```
              series: [{
                          name: "Linha 1",
                          data: [2, 2, 2, 2],
                          color: "red"
                      },{
                          name: "Linha 2",
                          data: [4, 4, 4, 4],
                          color: "green"
                }],
```